# Chart displaying the same number on all y axis ticks

Tags: excel, vba, charts, axis

I am fairly new to VBA, so my provided code might be far from optimized.
However, I'd be happy to hear what can be improved!

I have a sheet with two columns of data, one cell for an entry, a scatter chart, and three buttons.
The chart is supposed to simply plot the two columns and add the value of the entry cell as a vertical line.
One button is supposed to refresh the chart (e.g. to adjust the axes).
Another one is supposed to show an example by inserting some data, stored in another hidden sheet, into the two columns as well as in the entry cell and after that refresh the chart.
The last button is supposed to simply reset the sheet, so that the data columns as well as the entry cell are empty and the chart should be hidden.

The Problem:
The refresh button however does not work.
It seems to resize the viewing field of the chart according to the newly entered data. But the numbers shown at the y axis are always 0.05.
I have provided a picture to show you what I mean:

[image: Sheet]
[image: Chart]

When I press the example button, the y axis shows correct values. I tried copying the data in the columns to a different sheet first, then refreshing the chart and then pasting the data back into the columns, with no success.

I noticed that when the chart shows only 0.05 and I click on the chart to "select data" and simply select the second series, the y values change to what they should be and I can close the window and it stays as it should be until I press the refresh button again.

Maybe my code has flaws that I am unaware of? Maybe I need to, instead of refreshing the chart, delete the old one and create a new one each time? However, I already tried that with the same result. Maybe the code must be written in a different sequence?

The example button:

```
Private Sub ExampleBtn_Click()

Call RefreshBtn_Click

Range("C5:D27").ClearContents 'data columns

Range("C5:D14").Value = Sheets("ExampleSheet").Range("A1:B10").Value
Range("O3").Value = 3.5 'entry cell

End Sub
```

The reset button:

```
Private Sub ResetBtn_Click()

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Visible = False

Range("C5:D27").ClearContents 'data columns
Range("O3").ClearContents 'entry cell
Range("C5").Select

End Sub
```

The refresh button:

```
Private Sub RefreshBtn_Click()

ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Visible = True

'range of Nachdruckzeit
Set zeit = Range("C5:C27")

'range of Masse
Set masse = Range("D5:D27")

yMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.max(Range("D5:D27")) + 0.02
yMin = Application.WorksheetFunction.min(Range("D5:D27")) - 0.02

'refresh the chart
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1)
    .Width = Range("F5:P30").Width
    .Height = Range("F5:P30").Height

    If .Chart.SeriesCollection.Count = 1 Then
        .Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
    ElseIf .Chart.SeriesCollection.Count = 2 Then
        .Chart.SeriesCollection(2).Delete
        .Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
    End If

    With .Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .XValues = zeit
        .Values = masse
        .Name = "Siegelpunktermittlung"
        .HasDataLabels = False
    End With

    t = Range("O3").Value 'entry cell
    With .Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Name = "gewaehlt"
        .XValues = Array(t, t)
        .Values = Array(0, yMax)
        .MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleNone
        .Border.Color = vbWhite
    End With
End With

'Cosmetics
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
  .HasLegend = False
  .ChartArea.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
  .PlotArea.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
  .SeriesCollection(1).MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleCircle
  .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(251, 243, 223)
  .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 140, 0)
  .SeriesCollection(1).MarkerForegroundColorIndex = -4142

  'x-axis
  With .Axes(xlCategory)
    .HasTitle = True
    .TickLabels.Font.Color = vbWhite
    .AxisTitle.Font.Size = 12
    .AxisTitle.Font.Color = vbWhite
    .AxisTitle.Caption = "Nachdruckzeit [s]"
  End With

  'y-axis
  With .Axes(xlValue)
    .HasTitle = True
    .MinimumScale = yMin
    .MaximumScale = yMax
    .TickLabels.Font.Color = vbWhite
    .AxisTitle.Font.Size = 12
    .AxisTitle.Font.Color = vbWhite
    .AxisTitle.Caption = "Masse [g]"
  End With
End With


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
ActiveSheet.Protect

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of your excelsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem:

The problem was that the data cells for the chart had a number format, which for whatever reason messed up the chart. Changing the format to standard solved the problem.

if anyone knows why this problem occurs when changing the cell format, please let me know.

Comment: What was the format that led to the undesirable axis label appearance.

Comment: I had it set to the default 'number' format, since they are columns containing nothing else but numbers.

Comment: Default would be 'General', which wouldn't do that. Was the worksheet formatted with the 0.000 number format? This would format all numbers between 0.0045 and 0.0054999 as 0.005.